# ¿Cómo implementar un forEach/map en un useState con typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, foreach, map

Me encuentro implementando un proyecto personal (con react) para aprender mejor **typescript** y me encontré con el problema que no sé qué tipo poner en el parametro del mapeo:

```
  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState< AxiosResponse[] | string[] >([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers().then((result)=>{
      setDataUser(result.data);
    })
  }, [])

  useEffect(()=>{
    dataUser?.forEach((obj: any) => {
      console.log(obj)
    })
  }, [dataUser]);
```

Esto es lo que trae dataUser:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es en el forEach, si no pongo que es de tipo any, me tira error.
Cuando le pongo de tipo string (nickname debería retornar dos string), me tira el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El tipo de `obj` deberías poder usarlo a partir de algún [DTO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_transferencia_de_datos) creado para recibir el dato de la respuesta. Por ejemplo: `(obj: { id: number, nickname: string, password: string}) => { ... }`. Aquí estoy describiendo el tipo de objeto recibido por la función flecha. Podrías escribir tu propia definición, por ejemplo: `export type UserDataDTO = { id: number; nickname: string; password: string }` y usarla directamente en la función flecha como: `(obj: UserDataDTO) => { ... }`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Por otro lado, el [esquema de respuesta de Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) contiene un atributo llamado `data`. Para indicarle a Typescript, el tipo de dato recibido como respuesta, puedes indicar el tipo en `AxiosResponse`, ya que el mismo está definido como genérico: `AxiosResponse<T>`, siendo `T` un indicador de tipo genérico, por lo cual podrías usar tu propio tipo. Por ejemplo: `AxiosResponse<UserDataDTO>`.

Answer (score 0):

primero sería conveniente crear una ‘interface’ o un ‘type’ con la estructura de tus datos. por lo que veo aquí es (id, nickname, password) por lo que podrías tomar este ejemplo:

```
interface interfaceEjemplo {
    id: number;
    nikname: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Luego puedes setear el tipo de dato a tu estado..

const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState<interfaceEjemplo[]>([]);

Al definirlo asi cuando quieras utilizar el foreach TS inferir el tipo de forma automática, pero tambien puedes asignarlo

```
dataUser?.forEach((oba: interfaceEjemplo) => {
    console.log(obj)
})
```

Con esto debería funcionarte y reconocerte los atributos sin problema.

Saludos